# pre-generate ID field for entering a new record?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm creating a winforms app using EF6, so i've created a new table, and a whole bunch of controls, mostly textboxes and comboboxes.

I'm very new to all this, but i know that i need to use a using statement for the "entities" context.

The Id field, is PK and Auto-increment (IsIdendtity = True) so if i don't specify a write to the ID field, it should get an automatically assigned ID when the new entity is tracked to the context right?

How would i validate this? or manually attempt to write my ID?

Reason for question?

i worked on something seperate and simple, adding/removing records.. somehow, the ID's have jumped up to 4000, and i've only entered and removed about 5 - 6 records. so how has it got to 4000 already? (no loop was used for my code either) and was the same, ISIdentity, auto-increment 1.

yet somehow.. records got ID 4001..

So this has lead me to believe i need to validate and restrict that data further, but because im an amateur, i've no clue where to start, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

C#/WInforms/EF6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related with the Sql Server. When you create an identity sql server creates that identity with cache and reserving identities amount of specified cache. When you restart your SQL Server you loose previously reserved values and this cache is created again and the amount of identities reserved again. So this causes gaps in your identity. You can turn it off but with a performance trade off.
For further reading check [this](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/how-to-eliminate-gaps-in-identity-values-in-sql-server-by-disabling-the-identity-cache.html)